# How should I install LeibICT for USSD applications?

Tags: c++, api, ussd

I was looking for an API for USSD apps programming and I found Leibcit but they don't explain how to install it. Could you help me?

Comment: The only hit on Google for those terms is this question. Perhaps you could contact whoever makes it and ask?

Comment: Looks like a proprietary solution, if you bought a license you probably have some tech support with it.

Comment: Why the -1? If its a programming question, then its a programming question.

Comment: @molbdnilo He's probably talking about this : http://www.leibict.com/products_ussd_developer_kit.html

Comment: Do you understand what USSD is? Where do you think your app runs?

Comment: @MSalters I know what USSD is. What I want is somebody who have already install Leibict (in the help document they say we can use it with visual studio) but they don't show how to integrate it to the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

LeibICT is not an open source based company, you should buy the USSD GW Lincence in order to get detailed information and 7x24 support.

Please visit www.leibict.com for more details.